Lambda function eventbridge trigger is not getting configured using the Terraform
I am trying to configure the lambda function and cloudwatch event bridge trigger for the lambda to trigger based on the crontab and also pass some parameters while triggering the lambda function.
I am passing my tf file configuration here.
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "dp_ing_sls_chr4g-om-lambda"
  filename      = "dp_ing_sls_chr4g-om-lambda.zip"
  handler       = "dp_ing_sls_chr4g-om-lambda.lambda_handler"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  timeout       = 900
  memory_size   = 192
  package_type  = "Zip"
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  ephemeral_storage {
    size = 512
  }
      
  tags = {
    product = var.tag
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "lambda_cron_trigger" {
  name                = "LambdaCronTrigger"
  schedule_expression = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"  # Runs at 12:00 PM (UTC) every day
}
    
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda_cron_trigger.name
  target_id = "LambdaTarget"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
  input = jsonencode({
    org = "CS",
    deployment = "dev"
  })
}
    
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "lambda_logs" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 3  # Set the retention period according to your requirements
}
    
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_invoke_policy" {
  name        = "LambdaInvokePolicy"
  description = "Policy to allow CloudWatch Events to invoke Lambda function"
  policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17",
      Statement = [{
         Effect   = "Allow",
         Action   = "lambda:InvokeFunction",
         Resource = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
      }]
   })
}
    
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "lambda_invoke_attachment" {
  name       = "LambdaInvokeAttachment"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_invoke_policy.arn
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn]
}
    
# # section for lambda iam role
    
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
       {
          Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
          Effect = "Allow"
          Sid    = ""
          Principal = {
            Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          }
       },
     ]
  })
}

When I am running this all the resources all getting created properly. I can see event bridge trigger as well in the cloudwatch but the trigger is not getting attached to the Lambda function.
With More research I got to know some policies are missing due to the trigger not getting configured to the lambda function.

It looks like you are missing the Lambda permission resource, which then allows some service (or a resource) to trigger it:
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_eventbridge" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromEventBridge"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda_cron_trigger.arn
}

